# better way to write scala function with conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this function which I'm using as a UDF in spark.

```
def convertRecipeTimeToMinutes: String => Int =
    (time: String) => {
      val size = time.size
      val res =
        if (size == 2)
          0
        else {
          var recipeTime = 0
          val builder    = new StringBuilder
          val slice      = time.slice(2, size)
          for (i <- slice) {
            if (i.isDigit) {
              builder.append(i)
            } else {
              if (i == 'H')
                recipeTime += builder.toInt * 60
              else if (i == 'M')
                recipeTime += builder.toInt

              builder.clear
            }
          }
          recipeTime
        }
      res
    }
```

It converts data into time in minutes.

**Sample Input Data**

```
xx25M
xx1H
xx1H30M
xx
```

**Sample Output Data**

```
25
60
90
0
```

it does the required job but I want to know and learn is there a better way to write this? Pattern matching, partial function or anything?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression to extract the hours and minutes from the string:

```
def convertRecipeTimeToMinutes: String => Int = { time =>
  val Time = """\D*(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?""".r 
  time match {
    case Time(hours, minutes) => 
      Option(hours).fold(0)(_.toInt * 60) + Option(minutes).fold(0)(_.toInt)
  }
}
```

Check https://regex101.com/r/vFkY9G/1 to see how this regular expression works.